# Bridge Wordpress Media API with custom tinyMCE plugin

Tags: plugin-development, media-library, tinymce, plugin-tinymce

In my tinyMCE plugin, I would like to be able to call the Wordpress Media manager introduced in WP 3.5.

I am currently working on a plugin that needs to fetch images from the library.
I know we can easily call the media manager from a plugin but problem is in my tinyMCE plugin I can't call the wp_enqueue_media() in order to make it work.
So is there any way to bridge tinyMCE with this media manager API ?

Comment: +1  for being very tricky with your question: I'm not completely sure I understand. You already got eh media button above every `WP_Editor` instance that's perfectly pasting images from the media library to both the visual/TinyMCE as well as into the textarea/text content.